# How to check a certain index of an array contains a value or not

Tags: java, arrays

I have 4 objects to place in an array. I can't place it if the index contains any other object. How should I check if there is an element or nothing in a certain index of an array in java. Example ;
I have an array called numList and it contains some values. I want to add another number to index 6. For this I have to check numList[6] contains a value or not.

Comment: As long as it's an array of reference types (like `Object`s), test for `null`?

Comment: Do you mean to know if an element at a given index in the array is already used ?

Comment: Please show us what you have already done. It will be helpful to see your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java an array of types other than built-ins is initialized to `null` values. Use a loop to find the lowest index at which a `null` is stored:

```
MyObject[] array = new MyObject[mySize];
... // Populate some locations in the array, then...
int placeAt = -1;
for (int i = 0 ; i != array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == null) {
        placeAt = i;
        break;
    }
}
if (placeAt != -1) {
    // You found the first index with a null
    array[placeAt] = myNewObject;
} else {
    ... // Array has no empty spaces - report an error and/or exit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't go crazy, just check if there is null inside given index, like so:

```
if (array[index] != null) {
     array[index] = yourObject1;
}
```

and so on. If you already assigned some object to this position, then it won't be nulled out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArrayList in java.
you can add method directly to the end of list by add() method and if you want to check index use indexOf(object o) method.